# Flamingo: Struct not assignable to Interface

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I am using [flamingo](https://github.com/i-love-flamingo/flamingo) to build an application. I have a module in my source with a structure resembling as below.

`some_interface.go`

```golang
package something

type SomeInterface interface {
    someMethod()
}
```

`some_struct.go`

```golang
package something

type SomeStruct struct {
}

func(s *SomeStuct) someMethod() {
}
```

Binding in some module

```golang
package something

type Module struct{}

func (*Module) Configure(injector *dingo.Injector) {

    injector.BindMulti(new(SomeInterface)).To(new(SomeStruct))

}
```

when I run `go run main.go serve`, I get the following error

```sh
panic: something#SomeStruct not assignable to something#SomeInterface
```

#### Update

This only happens when I have methods in my interface. If I remove the method from my interface. It seems to work.

Comment: This is a guess, because I am not familiar with flamingo: the error states `SomeStruct` is not assignable to that interface. `SomeStruct` does not implement `SomeInterface`, but `*SomeStruct` does, because you declared the method with a pointer receiver. So, either change that, or try `new (*SomeStruct)`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no help. I still get the same error.

Comment: type Shape interface {
    Area() float64
}

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Found the solution. Interface methods should be **exported**.

`some_interface.go`

```golang
package something

type SomeInterface interface {
    someMethod()
}
```

`some_struct.go`

```golang
package something

type SomeStruct struct {
}

func(s *SomeStuct) someMethod() {
}
```